# From a network pair frequency dataset, how to assign a corresponding count for each group and their association with another group?

Tags: r

Here is the dataset

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L), .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"), class = "factor"), 
V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ABC", 
"DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(3L,                                                                                                                                     
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this

```
   V1  V2 Freq
1  DEF ABC    3
2  GHI ABC    2
3  JKL ABC    3
4  MNO ABC    2
5  GHI DEF    3
6  JKL DEF    1
7  MNO DEF    2
8  JKL GHI    1
9  MNO GHI    1
```

I would like to create something like this

```
x       y
ABC     4
DEF     4
GHI     4
JKL     3
MNO     3
```

Note that ABC has an association 4 times with DEF, GHI, JKL, and MNO. This corresponds to line 1,2,3 and 4. JKL has an association 3 times with ABC,DEF, and GHI. This corresponds to line 3,6,and 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a couple of ways

1. We `split`, each column by the other into a `list`. Get the `lengths`, add (`+`) and `stack` it to 2 column data.frame

```
stack(lengths(split(as.character(df1$V2), df1$V1)) + 
       lengths(split(as.character(df1$V1), df1$V2)))[2:1]
```

-output

```
 ind values
1 ABC      4
2 DEF      4
3 GHI      4
4 JKL      3
5 MNO      3
```

---

2. Or do the `table` on the columns, `+` them, get the `rowSums`, and `stack` it

```
stack( rowSums(table(df1[2:1]) + table(df1[1:2])))[2:1]
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution can also be used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  select(V1, V2) %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(freq = map_int(value, function(a) pmap_lgl(df[-3], ~ a %in% c(...)) %>% reduce(`+`))) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  select(-name)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  value  freq
  <fct> <int>
1 ABC       4
2 DEF       4
3 GHI       4
4 JKL       3
5 MNO       3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try `table` + `stack`

```
> rev(stack(table(unlist(df[-3]))))
  ind values
1 ABC      4
2 DEF      4
3 GHI      4
4 JKL      3
5 MNO      3
```

or an `igraph` option with `degree` like below

```
> rev(stack(degree(graph_from_data_frame(df))))
  ind values
1 DEF      4
2 GHI      4
3 JKL      3
4 MNO      3
5 ABC      4
```

Comment: At first I tried `igraph` but ended up in some dark, gloomy places. I guess it's not safe for me yet.

Comment: Yes exactly, I just have to learn the basics first and then try to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count the occurrences of each item in both columns `V1` and `V2`.

This can be solved by reshaping and counting the occurrences in long format:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns("^V"))[, .N, keyby = value]
```

> ```
>    value N
> 1:   ABC 4
> 2:   DEF 4
> 3:   GHI 4
> 4:   JKL 3
> 5:   MNO 3
> ```

or with `dplyr` & `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("V")) %>% 
  count(value)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
>   value     n
>   <fct> <int>
> 1 ABC       4
> 2 DEF       4
> 3 GHI       4
> 4 JKL       3
> 5 MNO       3
> ```

Answer (score 1):

library `janitor` also helps

```r
janitor::tabyl(c(df$V1, df$V2))
#>  c(df$V1, df$V2) n   percent
#>              ABC 4 0.2222222
#>              DEF 4 0.2222222
#>              GHI 4 0.2222222
#>              JKL 3 0.1666667
#>              MNO 3 0.1666667
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Master of janitor also :D